# Cohomology of finite cyclic group is always torsion

Tags: group-theory, modules, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, torsion-groups

I'm following Evens' The Cohomology of Groups, section 2.1 where resolutions for finite cyclic groups are developed. I understood the final result for a finite cyclic group $G$ and a $G$-module $M$:

$$H^n(G, M) = \begin{cases}
M^G\text{, if }n = 0\\
M^G/TM \text{, if }n\text{ is even and non-zero}\\
_TM/IM\text{, if }n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$

Where $M^G$ represents the submodule of fixed points, $TM$ is the image of the action restricted to the group ring ideal $T = \{\sum_{1}^{|G|} g^i| G = \langle g \rangle\}$, $IM$ is the image of the action restricted to the augmentation ideal $I$ and $_TM$ is the submodule $\{m \in M| Tm = 0\}$. An exercise then follows:

> Show that if $G$ is a finite cyclic group and $M$ is a $G$-module, then $|G|H^n(G, M) = 0$ for $n > 0$. Hint: for $n$ odd, consider $|G|x - Tx$ for $x \in M$.

I've already solved it for $n$ even. It took me awhile to snap it, but it was pretty straightfoward once I've got a grip of what was going on. A week rolled over and I still can't figure out the odd case. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the augmentation ideal $I$ is generated over $\mathbb{Z}$ by the elements of the form $1 - g$ for $g\in G$. So if you take an element $x\in M$ such that $T (x) = 0$, then
$$|G|\cdot x = |G|\cdot x - T (x) = |G|\cdot x - \sum_{g\in G} g\cdot x = \sum_{g\in G} (1 - g)\cdot x \in IM.$$
(Sorry for not following your notation here, my $g$ is an arbitrary element of $G$, not a generator.)

---

By the way, it is true for any finite group that multiplication by $|G|$ kills $H^n (G,M)$ and $H_n (G,M)$ for $n > 0$. You will probably see a proof of this later (you can show this using the bar-resolution, as in [Weibel, *An Introduction to Homological Algebra*, Theorem 6.5.8], or using transfer maps, as in [Weibel, *An Introduction to Homological Algebra*, Exercise 6.7.8]).